# Estimators: What to use for placeholder in an accuracy prediction?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification

I'm using a `DNNClassifier` and a `LinearClassifier` (using two different models for the sake of comparison) in TensorFlow to conduct a binary classification on my data set. I've successfully gotten both models to work and output metrics about the accuracy. However, what I would like is to be able to get some type of array out containing all of the predictions the model made on the test. Ideally these predictions would have some probability associated with them as well.

Searching on StackOverflow and the TensorFlow GitHub page led me to these lines of code to extract a prediction:

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(results, feed_dict={?})
```

The only problem is that I have no idea what to put in the `feed_dict`. Most other askers of this question appear to not be using a premade estimator, and thus I was confused about where to find the equivalent of what they put in `feed_dict` within my own code. I tried using what I put in my `test_input_fn` method, but I got a `TypeError`. Some other key portions of my code look like this:

```
def get_features(array):
    return {'policy_state': np.array(array[:, 2], dtype=str),
       'tiv': np.array(array[:, 4], dtype=int),
       'veh_count': np.array(array[:, 5], dtype=int),
       'generation': np.array(array[:, 8], dtype=str),
       'modern_classic_ind': np.array(array[:, 17], dtype=str),
       'h_plus_ind': np.array(array[:, 7], dtype=str)}

train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x=get_features(my_data),
    y=np.array(np.array(my_data[:, 11], dtype=int)),
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True)

test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x=get_features(test_data),
    y=np.array(np.array(test_data[:, 11], dtype=int)),
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True)
```

I am happy to provide additional code/information if necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`tf.estimator.Estimator.predict`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#predict) method, which returns a generator of prediction results. Example:

```py
predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({"x": x_test},
                                                      batch_size=batch_size,
                                                      num_epochs=1,
                                                      shuffle=False)

predictions = estimator.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn)
for prediction in predictions:
  print(prediction)
```

Note `num_epochs=1` and `shuffle=False` to make the result stable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am now getting out some predictions, however I do not fully understand the format. I'm seeing two probabilities (one for each class I assume, this I understand), and then two integer values, and then some information about type. Rows have this format: `'logits': array([ 36.63014603,  38.20797348, -49.78499222], dtype=float32), 'probabilities': array([ 0.17110339,  0.82889664,  0.        ], dtype=float32), 'class_ids': array([1], dtype=int64), 'classes': array([b'1'], dtype=object)` Do you know where I could find some documentation on what this all means in tf?

Comment: @AbigailFox these are default predictions of the classifier. I think the best tutorial to start with is here: https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/estimators

Answer (score 1):

The Estimator API manages the `tf.Graph` and `tf.Session` by itself, it uses an `input_fn` to feed all related ops with values. There is no need to start a `tf.Session`.

Train your model:

```
est = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(...)
est.train(input_fn=train_input_fn)
```

Predict:

```
predictions = est.predict(input_fn=test_input_fn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should feed in numpy arrays for all your tf.placeholders.

Such as

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float, shape=[None,10])
weights = ... (define some weights)
results = tf.matmul(inputs, weights)
feed_in={inputs: np.zeros((1,10))}
```